# How to use git push prune to delete remote branches

Tags: git

I am wondering if `git push --prune` can clean up remote branches just as `git remote prune origin` does in the opposite direction.  Here is what the documentation says it does:

```
--prune
    Remove remote branches that don’t have a local counterpart. For example a remote branch tmp will be removed if a local branch with the same name doesn’t exist any more.
```

But I am confused as to what is meant by *counterpart* in the above.  Let me explain what I am trying to do by an example.

Lets create a remote-tracking branch like follows:

```
$ git checkout -b my-feature-branch && git push -u origin my-feature-branch
...
Branch 'my-feature-branch' set up to track remote branch 'my-feature-branch' from 'origin'.
```

So my interpretation is that `my-feature-branch` is the `local counterpart` that the documentation refers to.

Now delete this local counterpart as follows:

```
$ git branch -D my-feature-branch
Deleted branch my-feature-branch (was f7404b0).
```

I am now expecting `git push --prune` to delete the remote branch if I run it as follows:

```
$ git push --prune origin
Everything up-to-date
```

However, as you can see, even though the local counterpart is gone, `git push --prune` refuses to delete the remote branch.  While I know I can use `git push -d origin my-feature-branch` to delete the remote branch, I am trying to understand if `git push --prune` can do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git needs to know what to compare. Specify where to find refs.

```
git push --prune origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*
```

Or

```
git push --prune origin refs/heads/*
```

Another method is to push an empty ref

```
git push origin :my-feature-branch
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to expand a bit on [EncryptedWatermelon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58919035/1256452) here.  *Pruning*, in the context of `git fetch` and `git push`, has to take place with a multiple-name copy operation.

More specifically, refspecs have one of these forms:

- `source`
- `source:destination`
- `:destination`

or any of the above three prefixed by a plus sign `+`.  The *source* and *destination* parts can be unqualified names like `master` or `v1.2`, fully-qualified names like `refs/heads/master` or `refs/tags/v1.2`, or—and the rules allowed here vary a bit by Git version—a sort of dumbed-down variant of a *glob pattern* such as `refs/heads/*` or `refs/remotes/origin/*`.<sup>1</sup>

If you *don't* use a glob `*` in your refspec, pruning is nonsense.

If you *do* use a glob `*` in your refspec, *prune* means, effectively:

- copy the given source names to the corresponding destination names, *and*
- delete any matching destination name that was not a result of copying a source name.

Without the prune option, destination names that are not copied-over are left alone.

---

<sup>1</sup>Use only one `*`, and only by itself or prefixed and/or suffixed with `/`, on each side, to get something that works in all Git versions.  That is:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

is fine (and is the standard refspec for remote `origin`), as is:

```
+refs/pull/*:refs/heads/prs/*
```

to copy all pull requests from a GitHub repository into your own local repository.  But:

```
+refs/pull/*:refs/heads/pr-*
```

only works in *some* versions of Git.

Comment: Why `git push --prune origin refs/heads/*` worked but not `git push --prune origin refs/remotes/origin/*`?

Comment: @akostadinov: `git push` is (normally) used to set *branch* names in the remote; `refs/remotes/origin/*` are *remote-tracking* names. That would be why: the Git over at `origin` is being used in the normal way, so it needs *branch* names here.